# Loading screen on page before data are loaded

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, loading

I have page which got grid with loading animation on it.

What i need to do is to load data from the encrypted file and fill textboxes with it on that page.
And when its encrypted so its gonna of course take some time to load. Thats why i created loading animation.

I created function to load data asynchronously so i can show loading screen and after its loaded i just hide it.

Looks like this:

```
public ArtaSettingsPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        VpnSettingsSavedLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        LoadDataAsync();

        async void LoadDataAsync()
        {
            await Task.Run(
            () =>
            {
                var info = FileCryptoDecryptor.ReadEncryptedConfiguration("hakuna.xml.aes", Global_Variables.AppPassword);
                string ArtaVPNIPSecKey = info.ArtaIPSECKey;
                string ArtaVPNServer = info.ArtaVPNServer;
                string ArtaVPNUsername = info.ArtaVPNUser;
                string ArtaVPNPass = info.ArtaVPNPass;
                string ArtaLocalAdminPass = info.ArtaLocalAdminPass;
                string ArtaDomainAccUser = info.ArtaDomainAccUser;
                string ArtaDomainAccPass = info.ArtaDomainAccPass;

                string DecryptedArtaVPNIPSecKey = EncryDecryptor.Decrypt(ArtaVPNIPSecKey, "password");
                string DecryptedArtaVPNServer = EncryDecryptor.Decrypt(ArtaVPNServer, "password");
                string DecryptedArtaVPNUsername = EncryDecryptor.Decrypt(ArtaVPNUsername, "password");
                string DecryptedArtaVPNPass = EncryDecryptor.Decrypt(ArtaVPNPass, "password");
                string DecryptedArtaLocalAdminPass = EncryDecryptor.Decrypt(ArtaLocalAdminPass, "password");
                string DecryptedArtaDomainAccUser = EncryDecryptor.Decrypt(ArtaDomainAccUser, "password");
                string DecryptedArtaDomainAccPass = EncryDecryptor.Decrypt(ArtaDomainAccPass, "password");

                DCIPBox.Text = info.ArtaDCIP;
                VPNServerTextBox.Text = DecryptedArtaVPNServer;
                ArtaIPSecKeyPasswordBox.Password = DecryptedArtaVPNIPSecKey;
                ArtaVPNUsernameBox.Text = DecryptedArtaVPNUsername;
                ArtaVPNPasswordBox.Password = DecryptedArtaVPNPass;
                ArtaLocalAdminPassBox.Password = DecryptedArtaLocalAdminPass;
                DomainAccUsernameTextbox.Text = DecryptedArtaDomainAccUser;
                DomainAccPassTextbox.Password = DecryptedArtaDomainAccPass;
                DomainTextbox.Text = info.ArtaDomain;
            });
        }
```

Problem is when i call it i get Exception on `DCIPBox.Text = info.ArtaDCIP;` the line where im filling textbox with decrypted data.

"Calling thread have no acces to object because its owned by another thread".

I guess problem is when i use await it creates another thread to do work if im getting it right and objects like textboxes on my page is on different "main" thread.

Is there any other option how could i do it?

//EDIT

One idea would be fill textboxes not async after they are decrypted but im just curious if there is possibility to fill them async and show user already filled page with information.

Comment: There are these things called BusyIndicators: https://brianlagunas.com/extended-wpf-toolkitusing-the-busyindicator/ | https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/BusyIndicator

Comment: @Christopher looks interesting i'l give it try if thats what i need. Thanks.

Comment: @Christopher Ok that tool is cool but i still need to figure it out how can i update textboxes from different thread.

Comment: WPF/UWP is designed with the MVVM Pattern in mind. And in that pattern you never access the GUI directly. IIRC, the Dispatcher is responsible for getting stuff on the Main Thread without dealing directly with the View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

You can use dispatcher invoke to update objects from different thread like this:

```
DCIPBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => DCIPBox.Text = info.ArtaDCIP));
```